# UnexpectedValueException

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I installed a module via composer and now my page load this error [image: image of error i get]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like the problem is file permissions, run the following command please!

```
sudo chmod -R +775 .
```

Don't forget to also clean and flush the cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

let me know if this solved your issue !

Comment: Thank you! It works! Bless you.

Comment: You-re welcome, please up vote and mark as answered :)

Comment: Don't mean to nag you @brooll but could you please mark as answer if this solved your problem?

Comment: Hello man i don't know how to mark as answer

Comment: On the left of my answer you should have a grayed "check" image, just press there ;)